# Select data based on latest transaction date for each item

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have a query which I want it to list all latest transaction's price for each stock item. I've tried to use `MAX()` to list all latest transaction for each item without including the price and it works but when I included the price, the method will not work.

**Here's my query**

```
SELECT MAX(DocDate) AS DocDate, StockCode, Price
FROM StockPurchasePriceHistory spph
INNER JOIN Stocks s
ON spph.Stock = s.Id
GROUP BY StockCode, Price
ORDER BY StockCode ASC
```

**Output**

[image: sqltable]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use row_number

```
select * from (SELECT row_number()over(partition by StockCode order by DocDate desc) rn
 , StockCode, Price
FROM StockPurchasePriceHistory spph
INNER JOIN Stocks s
ON spph.Stock = s.Id
) a where a.rn=1
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
SELECT MAX(DocDate) AS DocDate, StockCode, sum(Price) as Price
FROM StockPurchasePriceHistory spph
INNER JOIN Stocks s
ON spph.Stock = s.Id
GROUP BY StockCode
ORDER BY StockCode ASC
```

Comment: I don't want to sum the price. I just want to get the price for that specific date.

Comment: what is the error ? price column is in which table?

Comment: I want to get is the price of the latest transaction for each item. If you see on the image, For example, `ACS-000005` latest transaction is `2017-10-16` and the price is `55.00`. It should show only that row instead of multiplying it just because the prices are different for the same item.

Answer (score 0):

This is a good place to use `APPLY`:

```
SELECT spph.DocDate, s.StockCode, spph.Price
FROM Stocks s CROSS APPLY
     (SELECT TOP (1) spph.*
      FROM StockPurchasePriceHistory spph
      WHERE spph.Stock = s.Id
      ORDER BY spph.DocDate DESC
     ) spph;
```

With an index on `StockPurchasePriceHistory(Stock, DocDate desc)`, I would expect this to be a bit faster than alternatives using window functions and approximately as fast as a correlated subquery.